# ios viewcontroller to call child viewcontroller inside container

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `masterViewcontroller` with the `container` on it and a `2ndViewController` embeded via storyboard in that.  I am wondering how to access the 2ndViewController from the `masterViewController`.

I have seen about using prepare for segue but this doesn't seem to get called for when my viewController in the container is shown.  Is there something I need to hook up for it to appear in the prepare for segue function?

Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `prepare(for segue: sender:)` in the `masterViewController` class.

The segue needs an identifier in the storyboard. In `prepare`, you then check if the segue to be prepared for is the one you gave the identifier to via `segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier"`.

Then you can resolve the embedded ViewController as your `2ndViewController` like so:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
    if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" { 
        let child = segue.destination as! 2ndViewController
    }
}
```

By the way, if you use `as!`, you're force-unwrapping `segue.destination` as your `2ndViewController` class. If you're not 100% certain this segue will always have that class as it's destination, consider instead using `as?` to treat `child` as optional and then doing additional checks for it's existence before attempting to use it.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  So if I add that method to the `masterViewController` and simply put a `print("in prepare function")` I see nothing in the logs.  Any reason why this function would not be called?  I assume I have not set up something correctly.

Comment: @Matt could you edit your original question showing how you implemented it and what your problem now is?

Comment: Hey @Tom I am going to mark your answer as correct as I expect that to work.  As I was grabbing the code to add to the question I noticed I may have stuffed up my classes.  Thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks @Matt! If you figure out how you may have gone wrong in your code and you find it might be a common mistake, don't hesitate to add it as a comment or as an edit to your original question.